# Same query ,same database gives different result on mongoshell & angularJs factories.js

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, strongloop

I  just tried to impliment mongoDB Geospacial queries on my web application . Web application using strongloop/loopback as backend & angularjs a front end . 
There is  25554 number of data inside on "restaurants" model .

I just want impliment the below command on angularJs factories.js

```
db.restaurants.find({ location:
   { $geoWithin:
      { $centerSphere: [ [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ], 1 / 3963.2 ] } } })
```

factories.js sample code attached below .
[factories.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhhXN.png)

it returns an array of 25554 length.

[result log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hTuj.png)

But i run the same command on mongo shell & got the response array count as "420"

```
>db.restaurants.find({ location:{ $geoWithin:{ $centerSphere: [ [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ], 1 / 3963.2 ] } } }).count()
>420
```

what is the issue ? why i'm getting different result on same query on same database on different platforms?

Comment: Uhm, it is *not* the same query. The radius is different.

Comment: Sorry !! that was my mistake .put 5 miles instead of 1 mile on sample code given above . but actual program run the same query . you can check the screenshot attached (factories.js) .  I edited the question . Is it ok now ?